# Compare and delete row under multiple conditions

Tags: r

I want to delete the entire row if the current value of “Store Nbr”  IS NOT  equal to the previous “Store Nbr”, AND current “OH Qty” is equal to 0.

```
     Store Nbr  POS Value    OH Qty
1:      1        10          100
2:      1        20          200
3:      2        30           0
4:      2        40          400
5:      2        50          500
```

For example, in Row 3: Store Nbr[3] != Store Nr[2] & OH Qty[3] == 0, then delete   row 3

Result:

```
     Store Nbr  POS Value    OH Qty
1:      1         10          100
2:      1         20          200
4:      2         40          400
5:      2         50          500
```

Our current code is:

*Assuming that data store the df from above

```
New_df = data[{
                ( data$`Store Nbr` != shift(data$`Store Nbr`, 1L, type "lag")) 
                    && (data$`OH   Qty` == 0))
                 } , ]
Head(New_df)
```

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: (How long has it taken me to recognize that StackOverflow now accept triple-backtick [code-fences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-fenced-markdown-code-blocks) with [syntax-highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)?)

Answer (score 0):

A not so elegant solution, for the future please from workable data.
My loop is keeping any row that is `TRUE` for either argument.

```
new_df = dat[1,]
for (i in 2:nrow(dat)){
  if (dat$Store.NBR[i] == dat$Store.NBR[i-1] | dat$OH.Qty[i] != 0){
    new_df <- rbind(new_df, dat[i,])
  } 
}
```